# BigQuery Update where WHERE condition has multiple rows (Limit Update)

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, sql-update

I have a problem when trying to map data from a table with data from another table in Google BigQuery. To make it simple:
I have the `dataTable` with column `data_modelname, data_version, data_date`.
The `mappingTable` contains `mapping_modelname, mapping_version, mapping_date`.

When I try this code,

```
UPDATE dataTable
SET
    dataTable.data_date = mappingTable.data_date,
    dataTable.data_version = mappingTable.data_version

FROM mappingTable
WHERE 
    LOWER(data_modelname) IN (
    SELECT DISTINCT LOWER(mapping_modelname) AS distinctModel
    FROM mappingTable 
    WHERE mappingTable.data_version IS NOT NULL 
    )
```

I am getting the following error message from BigQuery:

> UPDATE/MERGE must match at most one source row for each target row

The select distinct statement returns the list of ~300 distinct models. Thus, when considering the WHERE-condition, there will be only one result where e.g., LOWER(data_modelname) is LOWER(ABC123).

Unfortunately my `mappingTable` contains more than one entry per model (duplicates), but I only want the first found entry. `Updating with LIMIT 1` did not work. 
I also tried this code, with a mapping table with less entries and thus no duplicates. This worked well. However, it returns the same error when there is more than one modelname.

```
WHERE LOWER(data_modelname) = LOWER(mapping_modelname)
```

Could you please help me to insert (update) the from the `mappingTable.data_date` and `mappingTable.data_version` from the `mapping table` into the `data table` w`here the data_modelname is mapping_modelname.` 
Further it would be great to be able to use some wildcards or regular expressions for mapping the modelnames, e.g. WHERE LOWER(data_modelname) IS LIKE '% mapping_modelname %'.

Thanks a lot.

---

**Edit, new problem:**

I now came across another problem. Same situation and tables, but what I now need to do is to update the field `data_date_Installed` where model and `data_version_Installed` are the same. So in my `data-table` there is a version-field "3.4" and `data_model "ABC123"`. In the `mapping-table` there is also `mapping_model "ABC123"` and many different versions in the `mapping_version_Installed`, and of course also "3.4" and the corresponding date of that version in the field `mapping_date_installed`. 
I have tried this code, however it only matches 88 values out of 1m.

```
UPDATE dataTable dt
    SET dt.data_date_installed = mapping_date_installed,
    FROM (SELECT ARRAY_AGG(mt LIMIT 1)[ORDINAL(1)].*
          FROM mappingTable mt
          WHERE mt.data_installed_version IS NOT NULL
          GROUP BY LOWER(mt.mapping_modelname)
         ) mt
    WHERE LOWER(mt.mapping_modelname) = LOWER(dt.data_modelname)
    AND
    data_version_Installed = mapping_version_Installed
```

Actually I can exclude an error in the tables: mapping values are correct and data-type is also correct (date = DATE and version = STRING) in both tables. Also comparing the strings with `LIKE instead of =` did not result in more matching values. 
Maybe the `GROUP BY statement` omits many possible installed_versions.

I am very happy and thankful, if you have some advice.

**Edit, SOLVED:**

It was possible to use the problem with simple SQL WHERE:

```
WHERE LOWER(mt.mapping_model) = LOWER(FINAL_modelName)
AND
data_date_installed = mt.mapping_date_installed
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use aggregation to get one row per `LOWER(model_name)`:

```
UPDATE dataTable dt
    SET dt.data_date = mt.data_date,
        dt.data_version = mt.data_version
    FROM (SELECT ARRAY_AGG(mt LIMIT 1)[ORDINAL(1)].*
          FROM mappingTable mt
          WHERE mt.data_version IS NOT NULL
          GROUP BY LOWER(mt.mapping_modelname)
         ) mt
    WHERE LOWER(mt.mapping_modelname) = LOWER(dt.data_modelname)
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes Array_AGG will work , mostly when we are updating one table but getting multiple value from mapper after joining two table.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30192193)